# How to download vs code with curl?

Tags: bash, visual-studio-code, curl

Seems like a simple question but

```
curl -L -o code.tar.gz https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/?dv=linux64cli&build=insiders
```

Gives me an HTML file. I tried many other combinations and even wget but couldn't make it work

Tried curl with many options, wget as well. Other answers here all mention the -L but in this case it does not work

Comment: because that URL is not a link to the vscode executable. It is a web page.

Comment: @GarrGodfrey I tried with the direct link as well

Comment: You also need to quote the url, because it contains shell metacharacters (especially `&`, which is a command delimiter).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the "direct link" (even that link is not really the "direct link" but a redirect to the direct link, thus you still need `-L` )
[image]

```
curl -L -o code.tar.gz 'https://code.visualstudio.com/sha/download?build=insider&os=cli-alpine-x64'
```

btw if you want to do a fancy/complex request, curl is the better option, but if you just want to download something, wget is the better option. For example, if your internet connection drops half-way, curl will just abort the download and return an error code. wget will try to resume the download from where it cut off, first by using a [Range request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Range_requests), and if it detects that the server does not support range-requests, it will restart the download from the beginning, up to 20 times (configurable), before giving up.